# Go above BASE_DIR in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, Quite Confused here.

This is BASE_DIR

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

└── MY_PROJECT
 │   MY_APP
 ├── BASE_DIR
 │   ├── settings.py
 │   │   /**
           ALL OTHER FILES **/
     └── manage.py
```

Now, How should I access my app directory in a settings.py file ??

[vision is the project name, api is the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D1A9.png)

This is BASE_DIR which gets printed:

/Users/roger/Desktop/WebDevelopment/mine/vision/vision

Comment: I don't know what you're asking here. BASE_DIR points to MY_PROJECT.

Comment: No, it's not pointing to my project if it was I could have accessed my MY_APP.  :(

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried printing the value? And where is BASE_DIR being defined?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? This seems more like an XY problem..

Comment: Daniel I have edited the post, you can have a look at there.

Answer (score 3):

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'MY_APP')
```

Comment: Now it's printing /Users/roger/Desktop/WebDevelopment/mine/vision/vision/../api

Comment: @AbhishekSoam yes that should work. If you try testing it by doing a `cd /Users/roger/Desktop/WebDevelopment/mine/vision/vision/../api` it should take you where you want it to